# Serving images in Django from mulitple paths

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using the django package sorl thumbnail for handling images.

The configuration in settings.py is:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/hammad/virt_env/virt1/gccFishing/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have images uploaded at two paths, the problem is images from the first path are only being rendered to the template.

This is my first path which is working fine.

- User profile pictures, which are getting uploaded at `/gccFishing/media/Images/` and are being rendered to the template with this code

> {% thumbnail  user.image "50x50" crop="center" as im %}
>
> ```
>  <img src="{{im.url}}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
> ```
>
> {% endthumbnail %}

This is my second path at which images are getting uploaded but are not being rendered to the template.

- Image upload path is `/gccFishing/media/Images/WallImages`. Im using this code to render them to template:

> {% thumbnail post.image "150x150" crop="center" as im %}
>
> ```
>  <img scr="{{im.url}}" width="{{im.width}}" height="{{im.height}}"></a>
> ```
>
> {% endthumbnail %}

Also when i try to access `{{post.image.url}}`

I get this error:

`The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it`

Any thoughts ?

## models.py

```
class Wallpost(models.Model):
    
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    points = models.IntegerField(default = 0, validators = [MaxValueValidator(100)])    # relate this to user reputation    
    #location
    #spot

    image = ImageField(upload_to = Imagepost_path, null = False, blank = True
```

)

## views.py

```
class Wallview(View):
    
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):    
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return render_to_response('wall.html', context, RequestContext(request))


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        image = request.FILES.get('image', None)
        text = request.POST.get('text', None)
        user = request.user
        try:
            wallpost = Wallpost.objects.create(text = text, image = image, author = user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
        except:
            return  HttpResponse('You should login to post')



def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = {}
            try:
                posts = Wallpost.objects.order_by('-posted_on')[:20]    
            except Wallpost.DoesNotExist:
                posts = None
            context['posts'] = posts
        return context
```

Comment: 1.Are the images in the dir WallImages? 2.Are you passing the {{post}} variable to the template, if so, what type of object is it?

Comment: Yes the images are getting uploaded to WallImages dir. And yes I'm passing the post object to the template. Post is an instance of a model with ImageField.

Comment: {{post.image }} gives this value : /gccFishing/media/Images/WallImages/image.jpeg. But {{post.image.url }} gives the no attribute error.

Comment: There's your answer, partially. {{post.image}} is a relative filepath string, not an object that understands url. You must be creating a different object when you upload your images using the second path. Can you post your model and view codes?

Comment: And the get_context_data method please.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ModelForm to handle the get and post of the file. You then only need one view method as well, not a get() and post(). :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import YourModelForm

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YourModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # file is saved
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = YourModelForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

All the logic to save the correct objects is handled for you. I suspect you aren't saving the correct object type in your WallPost image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, that's  not what I want. The Wallpost object is working fine, problems with the image rendering from url template tag. The images rendering just fine with its path.